# Unity - Rotate around pivot while looking at mouse pointer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want a curved platform to face towards the cursor and rotate around a red ball in the center (0f, 0f), while keeping a distance of 0.6f from the ball. Essentially the platform would want to keep as short distance from the cursor as possible, without escaping the red balls gravity.

[(Picture of the platform and the red ball)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkb7j.png)

I tried using ScreenToWorldPoint in transform.LookAt to make the platform look at the cursor, however this will rotate the platform around its own axis, not the balls. RotateAround didnt work for me neither, as i want to be able to rotate the platform with my mouse.

Im wondering if i could set a custom axis for the platform and then rotate it towards the cursor?

Comment: Put your platform in an empty object and just rotate the empty object towards your mouse. The empty object needs to be on the same position as the ball and you can than just use the delta from the platform to the empty object

Comment: @keil did you find an answer to this that worked for you?

Comment: @Ruzihm Yes. As Z3RP said, I added an empty gameobject as a parent and just rotated it rather than the actual platform.

Answer (score 2):

With the local direction of the platform the you want to point at the cursor as `Vector2 localForwardDirection`, the distance you want from the surface of the ball `float distFromBallSurface`, and the radius of the ball `float ballRadius`:

Rotate the platform (you can use [`Quaternion.FromToRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html) to rotate the "front" to be from whatever direction to point towards the cursor), then place it accordingly:

```
Vector2 ballToCursor = cursorPositionWorldSpace - ballObject.position;
platformObject.rotation = Quaternion.fromToRotation(localForwardDirection,ballToCursor);

platformObject.position = ballObject.position 
                          + ballToCursor.normalized * (ballRadius + distFromBallSurface);
```